# C functions in c++

Tags: c++, c, methods

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "blocknode.h"

 using namespace std;

class MemoryManager
{
public:
MemoryManager(unsigned int memsize);
unsigned char * malloc(unsigned int request);
void free(unsigned char * blockptr);
blocknode *getFirstPtr();
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out,const MemoryManager &M);

private:
unsigned int memsize;
unsigned char *baseptr;
blocknode * firstBlock;

void mergeForward(blocknode *p);
void splitBlock(blocknode *p,unsigned int chunksize);
};
```

Here is the BLOCKNODE.h file

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct blocknode
{
  unsigned int bsize;
  bool free;
  unsigned char *bptr;
  blocknode *next;
  blocknode *prev;

  blocknode(unsigned int sz,unsigned char *b,bool f=true,blocknode
  *p=0,blocknode *n=0):
  bsize(sz),free(f),bptr(b),prev(p),next(n) {}
  };
```

CPP FILE

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "MemoryManager.h"

using namespace std;


ostream & operator<<(ostream & out,const MemoryManager &M)
{
blocknode *tmp = M.firstBlock;
assert(tmp);
while(tmp)
{
  out << "[" << tmp->bsize << ",";
  if (tmp->free)
 out << "free] ";
  else
 out << "allocated] ";
  if (tmp->next)
 out << " -> "; 
  tmp = tmp->next;
}
return out;
}

MemoryManager::MemoryManager(unsigned int memtotal): memsize(memtotal)
{
baseptr = new unsigned char[memsize];
firstBlock = new blocknode(memsize,baseptr);
}

blocknode *MemoryManager::getFirstPtr()
{
return firstBlock;
}

unsigned char * MemoryManager::malloc(unsigned int request)
// Finds the first block in the list whose size is >= request
// If the block's size is strictly greater than request
// the block is split, with the newly create block being free. 
// It then changes the original block's free status to false
{
blocknode * tmp = this->firstBlock;
assert(tmp);
while (tmp){
    if (tmp->bsize >= request){
        if (tmp->bsize > request){
            splitBlock(tmp, request);
            return tmp->bptr;
        }
        tmp->free = false;
        return tmp->bptr;

    }
    tmp = tmp->next;
}

}

void MemoryManager::splitBlock(blocknode *p, unsigned int chunksize)
// Utility function. Inserts a block after that represented by p
// changing p's blocksize to chunksize; the new successor node 
// will have blocksize the original blocksize of p minus chunksize and 
// will represent a free block.  
// Preconditions: p represents a free block with block size > chunksize
// and the modified target of p will still be free.

{
if (p->free == false || p->bsize <= chunksize) {
    cout << "Error splitting memory....exiting with error code 1" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
blocknode * heap = new blocknode(p->bsize,p->bptr + chunksize,true,0,0);
heap->bsize = p->bsize - chunksize;
heap->prev = p;
p->bsize = chunksize;
p->next = heap;
 }

void MemoryManager::mergeForward(blocknode *p)
// merges two consecutive free blocks
// using a pointer to the first blocknode;
// following blocknode is deleted
{

    blocknode * tmp = p->next;
    p->bsize += p->next->bsize;
    p->next = tmp->next;
    tmp->next->prev = p;
    delete tmp;

}


void MemoryManager::free(unsigned char *blockptr)
// makes the block represented by the blocknode free
// and merges with successor, if it is free; also 
// merges with the predecessor, it it is free
{
blocknode * tmp = this->firstBlock->next;
assert(tmp);
while (tmp) {
    if (tmp->bptr == blockptr) {
        tmp->free = true;
        if (tmp->free == true && tmp->next->free == true) {
            mergeForward(tmp);
        }
        if (tmp->free == true && tmp->prev->free == true) {
            mergeForward(tmp->prev);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The goal of this program is to pretty much simulate the C heap manager which deals with malloc() and free(). I am having trouble with the last four functions of the memory manager cpp file. (refer to the comments) The code compiles however my program crashes during runtime, it says that there is an unhanded exception at memory location XxXXXXXXX does anyone know what is causing this? Line 110 ("if(tmp->next->free == true)") is where the program breaks

Comment: Use a debugger. Also see [How To Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Run your program in a debugger so that at the very least you can find out which line of code is triggering the crash. And then keep going as your debugger can do a lot more than that to help you find the problem on your own.

Comment: While this has nothing to do with a supposed crash, it seems that your MemoryManager::free() has an obvious bug -- it's unable to free an allocated block if it's the first block in the list.

Comment: When you write code, you should start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then build up. In this case you seem to have written a lot of code before testing any of it, or worse, kept on adding code after you noticed the crashing. **Never add to code that doesn't work.**

Comment: "Line 110 ("if(tmp->next->free == true)") is where the program breaks". Keep going in the debugger. Check the values of each of those pointers (`tmp` and `tmp->next`) to verify that they are valid. Your code doesn't check for that at all - it probably should.

Answer (score 1):

When `MemoryManager::free()` calls `mergeForward()` (the first call to `mergeForward`()) as a result of what happens in `mergeForward()`, it looks like the tmp pointer used by `free()` will no longer be valid, because `mergeForward`() `delete`d it.

The derefence of `tmp`, immediately afterwards, will result in undefined behavior.

This is in addition to the other bug in `free()` that I noted in the comments.

Comment: nevermind my previous comment

Comment: I updated the free function and it does not crash, however when the program comes to execute free(), it loops infinitely

Comment: I'm sure if you carefully explain the logic that your free() function uses to your rubber duck, your rubber duck will explain to you what the bug is. You can find your rubber duck at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging